# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'comments'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

while runnig http://127.0.0.1:8000/blogapp/blogdata/53/ i get error AttributeError at /blogapp/blogdata/53/
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'comments'
and it says expected error location is views.py line 42 which is

comments=blogmodel.comments.all()

models.py

```
class Blogmodel(models.Model):
    author=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Newpost=models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    summary=models.TextField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    created_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    published_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title},{self.Newpost},{self.published_date},{self.created_date}'

class commentmodel(models.Model):
    blogmodel=models.ForeignKey(Blogmodel,related_name='comments' ,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    comment=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    active=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.comment},{self.blogmodel.title}'
```

views.py

```
def blogretrieve(request):
   blogmodel=Blogmodel.objects.all().order_by('-published_date')
   context={'blogmodel':blogmodel,}
   return render(request,'blogapp/blogretrieve.html',context)

def blog(request,pk):
    blogmodel=Blogmodel.objects.filter(id=pk)
    #comments = y.comments.filter(active=True)
    comments=blogmodel.comments.all()        #line 42 
    context={'blogmodel':blogmodel,'comments':comments}
    return render(request,'blogapp/blogpk.html',context)
```

urls.py
app_name='blogapp'

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('createblog/',views.blogview,name='blogview'),
    path('blog/',views.blogretrieve,name='blog'),
    path('signup/',views.signupview,name='signup'),
    path('login/',views.loginview,name='login'),
    path('logout/',views.logoutview,name='logout'),
    path('author/<str:pk>/',views.authorview,name='author'),
    path('blogdata/<str:pk>/',views.blog,name='blogdata'),
```

Answer (score 1):

You should retrieve a *single* item with [**`.get(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get), or even better, with [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404):

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def blog(request, pk):
    blog = get_object_or_404(Blogmodel, pk=pk)
    comments = blog.comments.filter(active=True)
    context = {'blog': blog, 'comments':comments}
    return render(request, 'blogapp/blogpk.html', context)
```

> **Note**: Models normally have no `Model` suffix. Therefore it might be better to rename <s>`BlogModel`</s> to `Blog`.

Comment: its not working,error rises again 'Blogmodel' object is not iterable

Comment: @shafquetNaghmi: `blog` is not a *collection* of `BlogModel`s, but a single `Blog` item, so you should *not* enumerate over it in the template, so no `{% for ... in blog %}`.

Comment: @shafquetNaghmi, sir Willem Van Onsem means run loop only for `comments` model, and for `blog`, access it as a object like `blog.author`,`blog.title` etc. and not run loop for single object, in your `template` file.

Comment: i want to know why it was not working when we were not using get_object_or_404

Comment: @shafquetNaghmi: because then you have a *collection* of items, and it makes no sense that a *collection* contains a `.comments` attribute.

Comment: can you please eleaborate it

Comment: @shafquetNaghmi: if you have a string 'foo', then you can use `'foo'.lower()`, but a list `['foo']` has no `.lower()`, that makes no sense since it is a list (collection) of strings, not a string itself. The same rationale is for model objects/querysets.